# validating input field after moving to another field and not on keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am currently validating an input field but my current issue is that i have it set to validate after every key stroke. I want to change it to validate after the cursor has been moved out from that input field not sure of the syntax.

This is my current input field:

```
<input type="text" id="EmailField" name="Email" placeholder="Email" data-val="true" data-bind="value:email, event: { keyup: validateEmail, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'}" required="">
```

my validateEmail function:

```
$this.validateEmail = function () {

            var regexEmail = ...Expression...;
            var result = regexEmail.test($('#EmailField').val());

            if (!result) {
                notify({title: 'Invalid Email', text:'Invalid email format', type:'error'})
            }
        };
```

Comment: I think you are looking for the onChange event in JavaScript

Comment: @charmless when i changed `event: { keyup: validateEmail, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'}` to `onclick:validateEmail()` i got `validateEmail` is not defined.

Comment: where is your validateEmail function defined?  Is it in the page or in a separate .js file?  You need to have the function defined or included before it is called.

Comment: @Charmless yes my validateEmail function is in a separate js file

Comment: the function isn't being found before it is called.  So, I think you should validate that the path to the .js file is valid and that it does appear in your source.  And, that the include looks similar to this: <script src="~/Scripts/validateEmail.js"></script>

Comment: if the function isn't being found - then another possibility is that there is a syntax error in the javascript file.  So then file isn't parsed correctly - resulting in this type of error too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use onblur event and call a function 
in that function you may use validations

```
<input id="a" onblur="fun(this);">
  <script>
    function fun(ab){
      alert(ab.value);
    }
  </script>
```

[jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/zilodaqehajo/1/edit)

The above code snippet uses onblur event of input

**Answer Updated**

Use blur instead of keyup in event

```
<input type="text" id="EmailField" name="Email" placeholder="Email" data-val="true" data-bind="value:email, event: { blur: validateEmail, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'}" required="">
```

Comment: I tried this but not sure why it is stating that validateEmail function is not defined

Comment: What are the technologies you are using? If it is javascript then my answer should work? Could you provide jsbin or jsfiddle of your code

Comment: i don't have the script called from within the html page but separate. I am also using knockout and jquery along with javascript. i updated my post with my function

Comment: Instead of "keyup" in event use "blur" so that you may get what you want to achieve answer updated

Comment: that worked for me changed keyup to blur and it worked fine - thanks a bunch